# How to do an Intersect query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two sql queries and I need the intersect between then. I know mysql does not have the intersect operand, so how could I do it? Tried some solutions I found online but they all return some syntax error. The queries are:

```
SELECT person_name FROM person NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM movie NATURAL JOIN role WHERE movie_name = 'Alien'
  ) alias1

SELECT person_name FROM person WHERE gender = 'f'
```

Comment: How are the `person` and `movie` tables related?

Comment: Natural joins are convenient, but less stable than other joins (that use ON or USING conditions) and do nothing to indirectly document your tables for the purpose of questions like this.

Comment: You can achieve it by join using ON condition with common column between two tables.

Comment: You can probably just add the WHERE clause from the second query to the first one.

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: @Uueerdo - I have some aversion to natural joins. I know it's a very personal opinion, but I find them error prone.

Comment: @TheImpaler I am averse to them too; I was remarking on the OP's use of them. If table structures change, the meaning of such queries do as well, and the queries contain no documentation on the fields that the author of the query expected them to join on. That is why (other than it's portability) USING is nice.

Comment: We were supposed to translate relational algebra statements into SQL, so where the RA used natural joins I just translated them into SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `JOIN` all three tables together, and apply both `WHERE` clauses.

Here is an example. It assumes that your `movie` table joins to your `role` table on a column called `movie_id`, as well as an assumption that you have a `person_id` column in `role` and `person` to join them. You'll need to change this query to use the columns that your tables use.

```
SELECT
    p.person_name
FROM
    movie m
    INNER JOIN role r
        ON (m.movie_id=r.movie_id)
    INNER JOIN person p
        ON (r.person_id=p.person_id)
WHERE
    m.movie_name='Alien'
    AND p.gender='f'
```

**Edit**: I've used `INNER JOIN` here, with a guess at the columns to join on, as opposed to keeping the OP's `NATURAL JOIN`. As the comments to the OP have mentioned, best practice is to explicitly identify the joins, and not rely on a `NATURAL JOIN`.